# How to iterate list of objects in spring thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

```
public class Members { 
    private String fname; 
    private String lname; 

    public String getFname() { 
        return fname; 
    } 

    public void setFname(String fname) { 
        this.fname = fname; 
    } 

    public String getLname() { 
        return lname; 
    } 

    public void setLname(String lname) { 
        this.lname = lname; 
    } 
} 

public class Greeting { 

    Map<String,List<Members>> templateMap; 

    public  Map<String, List<Members>> getTemplateMap() { 
        return templateMap; 
    } 
    public void setTemplateMap( Map<String, List<Members>> templateMap) { 
        this.templateMap = templateMap; 
    } 

}
```

From above code, how can i iterate and display values in **templateMap** in spring thymeleaf in html part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller method, you have to add it as an attribute to the Model like so: `model.addAttribute("map",getTemplateMap());` (make a Greeting object to get the templateMap from)

In ur HTML you then acces it like so:

```
<div th:each="stepEntry: ${map}"> // stepEntry now is each entry of your map. 
    <p th:text="${stepEntry.key}"></p> // this is the key value of the entry.
    <div th:each="member, iterStat : ${stepEntry.value}"> //this will iterate over the value (which is a list in this case) from the entry.
        <p th:text="${member.fname}"></p> //this prints the fname of each member in the list
    </div>
</div>
```